# Add border to video (FFMPEG)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to increase the canvas size of some videos with the content centered and a 50% padding added to each side. I am using FFMPEG primarily. I also have Handbrake and VirtualDub on hand. I am open to using something else if it gets the job done.

I do not want to scale the original video down.

Here is some code I could not get working:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vf "pad=width=ow*2:height=oh*2:x=ow/2:y=oh/2:color=black" output.webm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `iw`/`ih` instead of `ow`/`oh`:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf "pad=iw*2:ih*2:iw/2:ih/2" <output>
```

Otherwise, the pad filter cannot calculate what size you want, since the output width/height will only be defined once the padding is done.

The option names are not needed, neither is the definition of black as background color (it's the default).

If your output file is of lower quality than the input, this is because ffmpeg will re-encode the video with the default encoder for the chosen output format (e.g., `libvpx-vp9` for `.webm`, or `libx264` for `.mp4`), with default quality settings. What you should probably do is choose a high enough bitrate (with 2-pass encoding) or a good enough constant quality factor (CRF). See the [VP9](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) or [H.264](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) encoding guides for more info on how to change the quality for these particular codecs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually posting from the office and typed out the question from memory of working on it for many hours last night. I did mean to use `ih/iw` and I will update the question. I couldn't get it to work with `pad` at all. I would be pleasantly surprised if this works!

Comment: I do try everything I post, so this should work in your case as well. I don't see why it would fail. Since you edited the question, that renders my answer invalid… please add the whole command-line output so we can diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Thanks again, maybe I just needed to sleep on it and talk it out. :)

Comment: Ok, sure! I rolled back the question to its initial state. If you have some updates for me, just edit your post again and ping me here.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll flag your answer as the winner when I get home to check it out.

Comment: The resulting video is not the same quality as the input. Do you know how I can achieve the border without sacrificing quality?

Comment: See the edits to my answer above. Set, e.g., `-c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 10` to achieve a high quality output with VP9. You could also go lossless, but then the output file would be huge.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671252/how-to-add-black-borders-to-video/56179969#56179969

Comment: do `-c copy` to keep original quality, save time, no recoding

Comment: @Zimba That will not work. When you add a filter, you cannot copy the video.